# ZuulException: forward error with Zuul-Eureka

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm facing a `ZuulException: forward error`  when routing with Zuul and Eureka.

The error not occur during the first minutes but after 1 or 2 mn I get this weird error.

I'm using **spring boot 1.4** and **spring cloud Camden**

If you want to reproduce the error or see my project: https://github.com/Seb69/Spring-demo-ZuulException/tree/master

Eureka config:

```
server:
    port: 9999

spring:
    application:
        name: eureka-server
eureka:
   instance:
     hostname: localhost
   client:
     registerWithEureka: false
     fetchRegistry: false
     serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Service-Gateway config (Zuul):

```
server:
    port: 1111
spring:
    application:
        name: service-gateway

# ZUUL (Load balancing)
zuul:
    ignoredServices: '*'
    routes:
        service-server:
            stripPrefix: true
            path: /api/**
            serviceId:  SERVICE-SERVER


# EUREKA (Service registry)
eureka:
    instance:
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
        leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:9999/eureka/
```

Service config:

```
server:
    port: 8095
spring:
    application:
        name: service-server

eureka:
    instance:
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
        leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:9999/eureka/
```

Here is a short version of my stack trace:

> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
>
> Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Number of retries on
>   next server exceeded max 1 retries, while making a call for:
>   mbp-de-andre:8095
>
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mbp-de-andre

Comment: Your `eureka.instance.lease*`  values are very low.

Comment: I have tried with a higher figure but this doesn't solve my issue

Comment: The unknown host exception is odd. Can you ping that host?

Comment: No I can't ping mbp-de-andre. This error occur at the very end of my stack trace, so I suppose this is not the root cause of my issue

Comment: It is the cause of your issue, zuul can't connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

**FIX:**
So, I finaly succeed to make it work !

My problem came from my Macbook Hostname,

Last hostname was: `mbp-de-andre`

I modify it and I set: `MacBook-Pro-de-ANDRE.local``

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say another fix might be missing dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
</dependency>
```